# Failure Handling of transformations in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I read all the data into a pyspark dataframe from s3.
I apply the filter transform on the dataframe. And then write the dataframe to S3.

Lets say the dataframe had 10 partitions of 64MB each.
Now say for partition 1, 2, and 3 the filter and write were successful and there data was written to S3.

Now lets say for partition 4 the filter errors out.

What will happen after this. Will spark proceed for all the remaining partitions and leave partition 4, or will the program terminate after writing only 3 partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant parameter for non-local mode of operation is: `spark.task.maxFailures`.

- If you have 32 tasks and 4 executors and 7 have run and 4 are running with 21 tasks waiting in that stage,

  - then if one of the 4 fails more times than `spark.task.maxFailures` after being re-scheduled,

    - then the Job will stop and no more stages will be executed.
    - the 3 running tasks will complete, but that's it.

A Job of multi-stages must stop, as a new stage can only start when all tasks of previous stage complete.

Comment: Cool. How did you test the solution? Can you please share any useful links.

Comment: I know from contracts in the past. I am on holidays now so not really using a Spark cluster. You can find links out there. google on that param. But that is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Transformations are all or none operations. In your case above, Spark will crash with errors from partition 4.

Comment: So the program will terminate after writing 3 partitions?

Comment: Answer is inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah. I think the program will continue for the remaining partitions. Because for every partition threre is a task and if one of them fails that does not mean others will also fail.Am i right?

Comment: I think you are right, but we are in the business of knowing where answers are concerned. Questuon is not pyspark specific either.

Comment: “But we are in the business of knowing where answers are concerned“. Sorry. Did not get this line

Comment: Providing an answer is on the basis of knowing.